# Positioning elements at top right of <div>

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTNqe/9/) that contains a div, some text and a button.

I'd like to position the button on the top right of the div no matter how big the div gets, or how much text is in the div.

I though something like

```
float: right;
position: relative;
```

may do the trick, but this doesn't work, because the 'text' in the div will push the button down.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe `absolute`ly position the button to the top right, instead of `relative`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use absolute positioning, you can simply use `top` and `right` to position the button relative to the top right corner.

```
#myButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pTNqe/11/)

Please note that when absolutely positioned, the element is [taken out of the flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning), so other elements (like that `<p>` there) can go "under" it if they are big enough.

Comment: Only in your fiddle you made the `<div>` wrapper an absolute too... It's not always possible to do that!?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you want is absolute positionning, so try that

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changed the button styles to

```
#myButton {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:5px; 
    right: 5px;    
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?