# positioning scalable element relative to upper right parent's corner and own lower-left corner

Tags: html, css, position

I would like to make an optional data on an element to appear tooltip-like on the upper right of the element. I have problems positioning it though, as both the element (container) and the tooltip (offset child) may contain variable amount of data and are allowed to be scaled dynamically if there's too much data.

The picture below shows what I want to achieve:

[image: positions]

I don't have influence on the "variable" dimensions - browser flows them to contain the data automatically. I want to be able to specify the "set" distance and keep it constant no matter how the boxes are auto-scaled due to variable content.

Can I achieve this with pure CSS? If so, how?
('top', 'bottom', 'left' and 'right' all position the upper left corner of the offset child. How do I make the lower left corner the "handle"?)

Comment: What you have to do is creating above your parent div the exactly same offsetchild with a visibility hidden. (this will adjust the variable height). Then, you have to create two divs. The parent container div, and the child container div. Then, float to the left your parent div of the parent container div and to the right your offset child.
If you create a jsfiddle, I can give you the code

Comment: @SF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114819/positioning-elements-at-top-right-of-div

Comment: @hitautodestruct: That offsets upper-left corner of the child by a fixed value, not the lower-left).

Comment: @SF This is one of the oldest css tricks in the book, used to use it for rounded corners, but now I use it for close buttons. I'm writing you an answer but be aware that this information exists all over the net.

Comment: @hitautodestruct: Close buttons and rounded corners don't tend to change their height and width unpredictably. You can position them with trivial `top:0; right:0;` just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

Consider this HTML construct:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        <div class="child">Aliquam convallis rhoncus lacus...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS styling:

```
.wrapper {
    outline: 2px dotted blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The `.wrapper` is simply to provide a layout context for demonstration purposes.

For the parent element, use `position: relative`.  For the child, use `position: absolute` and place the left/bottom corner at 100%, which corresponds to the upper right corner of the parent box (regardless of its size).

To control the offset, adjust the margin of the child element.

This is all pretty standard CSS 2.1 so it should work in all browsers.

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6LTh4/

Comment: I wish it wouldn't move the Parent down as the Child grows, but I guess I didn't specify this, so...

Comment: Your layout needs to have enough space so that the tool tip can be visible.  Another issue with using `absolute: position` is that the element's width will shrink-to-fit the content when it is positioned outside of the containing block.  Some how, you need to allow for a reasonable width to either be specified or computed or inherited.  How you best do this depends on the details of where you implement the tool tip panel.

Comment: I achieve reasonable width with `min-width`. It's when the data exceeds that when the box starts growing.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cyjJq/

### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.parent{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    top: 100px;
    left: 75px;
    background-color: green;
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 40%;
    top: -40%;/*same as height*/
    left: 100%;/*entire width of containing div*/
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you want to make the child further away, simply decrease `top`/increase `left`

Comment: Unfortunately this enforces fixed height and width of both elements. I can't afford that - I can at best use `min-width` and `min-height` and I'm to expect both minima to be exceeded: http://jsfiddle.net/XasfD/

Comment: @SF You need to take 5 minutes and elaborate on the following:  I want the "set" dimension to be constant though.  It sounds like you want the distance from the upper right corner of the parent to the lower left corner of the child to be specified.  Please say so explicitly in your question.